# Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/util/Pair

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a Unity app that uses an Android library. The library code makes use of the **Pair** class, the code snippet is the following:

```
private Pair<Connection, Connection[]> parseConnectionOptions(Connection connDefault) throws ConfigParseError {
    Connection conn;
    if (connDefault != null)
```

I generate a java library (aar) and use it from my Unity app. However when I build the app and try to run it I get the following error

```
11-29 13:17:25.166 19667 19701 E Unity   : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/util/Pair;
11-29 13:17:25.166 19667 19701 E Unity   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/util/Pair;
```

I've already investigated if there's some similar issue but didn't found any useful information. I don't understand why this class is missing. Any hints are more than welcome.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your import statement? That `L` shouldnt be there

Comment: No, I think the "L" is inserted by the exception handles. The code at Android builds correctly it fails on runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/app/ActivityManagerCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141800/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroidx-core-app-activit)

Comment: Unfortunately no because the missing class is different.

Comment: @rkachach Were you able to resolve this? I'm currently facing same issue

Comment: unfortunately I don't remember how I fixed it. I think it just disappeared once I moved to a higher API level but not sure to be honest.